# Error message in case of LEFT JOIN, false

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

As the title says, I have a situation in which I'm doing a select between two tables, to verify through a left join, that there are equal parameters for then, to pull out a custom echo.

As you can see from the table at the bottom I have 3 companies (table: tev_Evidenze)

two of these have the field (ID_evidenza)

therefore it means that the company 1 and 5, the company 6 owns it but there is no ha.

This is what the left join does, so I would like to show, example

```
1 true
5 true
6 false
```

scheme of my db:

```
TABLE: tev_Evidenze                 
id_struttura
ID_evidenza
id_tipo_accreditamento

id_struttura. | ID_evidenza | id_tipo_accreditamento
      1           420               1
——————————————————————————————————————————————————
      1           422               5
——————————————————————————————————————————————————
      1                             6
```

AND

```
TABLE: tev_Tipi_accreditamento
ID_tipo_acc
id_struttura

ID_tipo_acc. | id_struttura | 
      1           1         
——————————————————————————————
      5           1         
——————————————————————————————      
      6           1
```

Code:

```
<?php
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze
ON tev_Tipi_accreditamento. ID_tipo_acc = tev_Evidenze.id_tipo_accreditamento
WHERE tev_Tipi_accreditamento.id_struttura = tev_Evidenze.id_struttura GROUP BY tev_Evidenze.id_struttura";
$query = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_string);
?>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
<?php 
    if($query==0)  {
        echo $row['id_struttura']. "SI";
    }else{
        echo $row['id_struttura']. "no";
    }?>

<?php } ?>
```

At this moment they go out alone

```
1
5
```

but it doesn't come out 6, I would like to release the results when the outcome of the left join is not satisfied

Comment: What does *"I would like to release the results when the outcome of the left join is not satisfied"* mean? What does "Release" and what does "Left join is not satisfied" mean? Your WHERE predicate belongs with your ON clause since it's part of the tables' relationship. And you can anticipate, given your sample data, that all three rows will be returned, but aggregated into one single row. You are not using `Sum()` so no addition will occur. Please post your desired results in your question so we can guide you to a better query.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a filtering condition in the `WHERE` clause, that should be on the `ON` clause.

Change your query from:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento 
LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze ON tev_Tipi_accreditamento. ID_tipo_acc = 
          tev_Evidenze.id_tipo_accreditamento
WHERE tev_Tipi_accreditamento.id_struttura = tev_Evidenze.id_struttura 
GROUP BY tev_Evidenze.id_struttura
```

To (change on line 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento 
LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze ON tev_Tipi_accreditamento. ID_tipo_acc =
          tev_Evidenze.id_tipo_accreditamento
      AND tev_Tipi_accreditamento.id_struttura = tev_Evidenze.id_struttura 
GROUP BY tev_Evidenze.id_struttura
```

By using `WHERE` you were silently converting the outer join into an inner join, without even noticing.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the `GROUP BY` lacks all of the columns in the `SELECT` and will therefore produce unexpected results. OP mentions they want `6` as a result, yet no `Sum()` is present in the SELECT portion of the query to derive that aggregate.

Comment: @JNevill Yeah, that's a bug in MySQL that was fixed in version 5.7.5. Before that version MySQL silently (and randomly) used to choose values from one row, on the columns not mentioned in the `GROUP BY`. Nowadays, it shows an error (as it should).

Comment: in this case, with my echo i have always no: no 1no 5no

Comment: i want: 1 si 5 si and 6 no

Comment: @A.M In the if that follows the query, maybe you should check for if the value of `ID_evidenza` is null or not null.

Comment: @TheImpaler That was my biggest pet peeve. `ALWAYS_FULL_GROUP_BY=true` is a gift.

Comment: @TheImpaler how to make this?

Comment: @A.M To be able to help you easily I would suggest if you could create a SQLFiddle with the tables and a few rows of data. I could go there and write a running query for you. Can you do that? Here's the site: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't know this, do I need to register and then delete what I write, or delete it by myself?